Property get does not exist
I am trying to make a standard configuration package that will load all my configuration for an API server (more so a set of them) that can be called into multiple apps inside a monorepo built using Turborepo. With my current code I am getting an error of "Property 'get' does not exist on type". I am unsure why.
config/config.ts
import convict from 'convict';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

import path from 'path';

import { DeepReadOnly } from '@repo/types';

export const apiConfigSchema = {
    DEBUG: {
        default: '',
        doc: 'Debug settings',
        format: String,
        env: 'DEBUG'
    },
    DATABASE_URL: {
        default: '',
        doc: 'Database URL',
        format: String,
        env: 'DATABASE_URL',
        sensitive: true
    },
    LOG_LEVEL: {
        default: 'info',
        doc: 'Logger level',
        format: String,
        env: 'LOG_LEVEL'
    },
    PORT: {
        default: 3000,
        doc: 'Port',
        format: Number,
        env: 'PORT'
    },
    JWT_SECRET: {
        default: '',
        doc: 'JWT secret',
        format: String,
        env: 'JWT_SECRET',
        sensitive: true
    },

    // Add more configuration here
};

dotenv.config({
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', '.env')
});

const config = convict(apiConfigSchema);

export type aipSchema = DeepReadOnly<typeof config extends convict.Config<infer T> ? T : never>;

export type ConfigKey = keyof aipSchema;

export default config;

index.ts in the configuration package
export * from './config/config';

The DeepReadOnly type from above
export type DeepReadOnly<T> = T extends Function
    ? T
    : T extends ReadonlyArray<infer R>
    ? ReadonlyArray<DeepReadOnly<R>>
    : T extends Map<infer K, infer V>
    ? ReadonlyMap<DeepReadOnly<K>, DeepReadOnly<V>>
    : T extends object
    ? { readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepReadOnly<T[P]> }
    : T;

My attempt at using the configuration package
import config from "@repo/configuration";
export function generateAccessToken(user: User) {
  return jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, config.get('JWT_SECRET'), { 
    expiresIn: '5m',
  });
}



Is the error related to config.get('JWT_SECRET') ? In this case check the type of the result of convict(apiConfigSchema). It seems it has not the used get method.

@LuCio Correct that is where the error is coming from. The get method should be coming off of it properly as shown in the docs here however it seems I have broken it in some way to result in that not being exported with the rest of it.

I used your code with convict v6.1.6 and it works. Since you're using Typescript make sure you also have the type-defintions as dependecy in your package.json. In my case it contains the following dependencies-object: "dependencies": {     "convict": "^6.1.6",     "@types/convict": "^6.1.6"   }
